# Exception when connecting to device

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet

I have a problem with connection to my Bluetooth device (HC-05). 
When call `BluetoothClient.Connect()`, sometimes exception occures - "An invalid argument was supplied.", or another. But sometimes device connects (usually at first connection)!
Do I have to close connection when I leave app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should close the connection and dispose the BluetoothClient.

```
private InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient BTClient = 
new InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient(); 
private System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream stream;
```

//Somewhere on the code:

```
stream = BTClient.GetStream();



public void Disconnect()
    {
            if (BTClient == null )
                return;

            try
            {

                if (BTClient != null)
                {
                    if (stream != null)
                    {
                        stream.ReadTimeout = 500;
                        stream.WriteTimeout = 500;
                        stream.Close();
                    }

                    if(BTClient.Connected)
                        BTClient.Close();
                    BTClient.Dispose();                        
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            } 

    }
```